# vb.net inline IF with OR... not evaluating

Tags: inline-if

I'm working on a small problem where I'm trying to show/hide a panel based on two criteria

1. A specific data field must not be blank
2. The specific data filed must also not equal "Not Relocatable"

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working for me (note that setting either one or the other criteria works just fine.)

```
        <asp:Panel runat="server" Visible='<%#If(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "_236")) Or Not DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "_236") = "Not Relocatable", True, False)%>'>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td class="align-right lightgreen">
                Buyer would consider relocating a business, if it is:
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3">
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "_236")%>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </asp:Panel>
```

Can anyone lend a hand to rectify this problem for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `<%# %>` is a *data binding* syntax, not an inline expression syntax. You cannot use procedural code inside of it like you can in the inline code `<% %>` tags.

Data binding tags must contain a single `Eval` or `Bind` function. If you need to do conditional branching based on those functions, you will need to do it using inline code around the binding tags.

Comment: I need to be able to evaluate databound content.  How would I do this without using data binding syntax?

Comment: also, this bit works just fine `<asp:Panel runat="server" Visible='<%#If(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "_236"), True, False)%>'>`

Comment: You need to change your boolean OR to an AND between the two clauses in the If() statement. Right now your statement is, "if the item isn't blank *or* if it isn't 'not relocatable', display the panel." If the item is non-blank and equals "not relocatable", it will meet the first condition and the second will be irrelevant.

Comment: Funny how a second pair of eyes can make all the difference. I've made plenty of errors like that myself.